# Lambda Query On Nested List Object

Tags: c#, linq

I've a data structure of something like this:

```
class A
{
    List<B> data;
}

class B
{
    C data;
}

class C
{
    List<E> data;
}

class E
{
    int Id;
    string Name;
}

function GetEById(int id, List<A> data)
{
}
```

Now I need to build a Linq Lambda Expression where Id = something. I don't want to go for nested loops.

Any help will be greatfull.

Comment: Welcome @Ahmad Bukhari to Stack Overflow, It's usually a good idea to have a sample data with the corresponding result.

Comment: It does not seem simple but this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50973631/linq-query-to-object-with-nested-list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your classes look like this:

```
public class A
{
    public List<B> Data { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public C Data { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public List<E> Data { get; set; }
}

public class E
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can create a method `GetEById` that uses [`Enumerable.SelectMany()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netframework-4.8) to flatten the results and pick the first `E` object that matches the id with [`Enumerable.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=netframework-4.8):

```
private static E GetEById(int id, IEnumerable<A> data)
{
    return data
        ?.SelectMany(a => a?.Data?.SelectMany(b => b?.Data?.Data))
        .FirstOrDefault(e => e?.Id == id);
}
```

Or you could collect all `E` objects into a `IEnumerable<E>` filtering with [`Enumerable.Where()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where?view=netframework-4.8):

```
private static IEnumerable<E> GetAllEById(int id, IEnumerable<A> data)
{
    return data
        ?.SelectMany(a => a?.Data?.SelectMany(b => b?.Data?.Data))
        .Where(e => e?.Id == id);
}
```

You can try this on [https://dotnetfiddle.net/](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1Qo9nI)

**Note:** You could also look into [Null-conditional operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) to ensure child properties don't execute if the parent property is `null`.

I would also name your class types better. Names such as A, B, C etc. don't really mean much, and makes it hard for the reader to understand what these classes do and represent.

Comment: FYI you don't need the null-conditional operator `?.` after `SelectMany` as that will never return `null`.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I needed. I was never comfortable with selectmany because I never looked into it But now after your answer I did and It make sense and seems very useful. Thank you.